# Separate methods of class by groups in Java

Tags: java, refactoring

1. I have a class that has many protected data members and many groups of different functions that handle these data members.
2. I want to separate these class by subclasses so that different groups of methods will be in different subclasses.

1.I have this class

```
class Student {
    protected String name;
    protected int courseNumber;
    protected TreeMap<String, Integer> marks;
    protected double successRate;
    protected Pair<String, Integer>[] conferences; //name, place


    void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    //... setters
    String getName() { return name; }
    //... getters

    //...constructors

    int getHashCode() {
        int res = 0;
        //...
        return res;
    }
    boolean less (Student b) {
        boolean ls = false;
        //...
        return ls;
    }
    //... functions to compare objects

    String lastConferenceName() {
        return conferences[conferences.length - 1].getKey();
    }
    //... some last data

    double marksMedium(String[] s) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            res += marks.get(s[i]);
        return (double) res / s.length;
    }
    //... some medium functions

    //... some group of functions

    //... some other groups
}
```

I want to do something like that

```
class Student{
    protected String name;
    protected int courseNumber;
    protected TreeMap<String, Integer> marks;
    protected double successRate;
    protected Pair<String, Integer>[] conferences; //name, place


    void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    //... setters
    String getName() { return name; }
    //... getters

    //...constructors
}

class StudentComparator{
    int getHashCode() {
        int res = 0;
        //...
        return res;
    }
    boolean less (Student b) {
        boolean ls = false;
        //...
        return ls;
    }
    //... functions to compare objects
}
class LastStudentInfoGetter{
    String lastConferenceName() {
        return conferences[conferences.length - 1].getKey();
    }
    //... some last data
}
class StudentMediumGetter{
    double marksMedium(String[] s) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            res += marks.get(s[i]);
        return (double) res / s.length;
    }
    //... some medium functions
}
class SomeStudentFunctions{
    //... some group of functions
}
///... SomeOtherClasses
```

It would be better if these classes don't use setters and getters

---

Upd

For example, I have this class

```
class Handler{
    void handle(){
        Student s = new Student();
        ///////........
        System.out.println(s.lastConferenceName());
        System.out.println(s.getHashCode());
    }
}
```

And I want handle() (or something like that) to work after transformation

Note that lastConferenceName() and getHashCode() are in different groups

Comment: You could make interfaces with those methods, then have `Student` implement them.

Comment: I want Student class to be smaller. I don't want to implement all the methods in Student class

Comment: If you want to access them, you have make their access scope protected or public. I'll add a code..

Comment: After that extends the Student class in your subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Extends the Student class as like follows from each your subclasses.

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int courseNumber;
    protected TreeMap<String, Integer> marks;
    private double successRate;
//  protected Pair<String, Integer>[] conferences; // name, place

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    // ... setters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    // ... getters

    // ...constructors
}

class StudentComparator extends Student{
    public int getHashCode() {
        int res = 0;
        // ...
        return res;
    }

    public boolean less(Student b) {
        boolean ls = false;
        // ...
        return ls;
    }
    // ... functions to compare objects
}


class StudentMediumGetter extends Student {
    double marksMedium(String[] s) {
        int res = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
            res += marks.get(s[i]);
        return (double) res / s.length;
    }
    // ... some medium functions
}

class SomeStudentFunctions extends Student {
    // ... some group of functions
}
```

Comment: If I do this way, I can not access other methods.
I need all the Student's methods.

Comment: When you subclassed, you can't access any private members in the super class. So you have to make them at least protected.